# Leveraging Wordpress Comments on Custom Plugin Object page

Tags: plugins, customization, comments

I have written a plugin that creates it's own tables to house the necessary schema for client's product. Then I created a single page that retrieves the custom object via passed in query string like so:

```
http://localhost/wordpress/my_object/?id=7
```

Where it would retrieve the item with ID 7 in it's custom table.

However the client would like to have commenting enabled on their custom object's page, with those comments obviously being related to the item with id 7.

Seeings how I don't create a page, or post for this object. **Is there any way to tie Wordpress Built In Commenting to this custom object ?**

Comment: While I wouldn't say it's impossible outright, endeavors like this usually drown in massive amounts of edge cases. Natively comments are engineered to go with post types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would enable comments for that page and save them with a comment meta holding your object's ID. To be more specific, this is how would I tackle this issue:

1. Hook into `comment_post` action and [save a comment meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta) called `my_object_id` with your custom object ID as a value when posting a comment from the relevant page.
2. To display only relevant comments, I'd [query the comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query) with `meta_key => "my_object_id"` and `meta_value` set to the actual object ID you're retrieving the comments for.

Comment: Nice solution.  WP has some phenomenal power with the hooks they provide, doesn't it?